# Revise data after grouping, mutate, split and review by gvlma

Tags: r, linear-regression, transformation, resampling

I will provide my code in the end. My issue is that I have to group, mutate and split my data so I can do a regression.

To test the regression I tried using gvlma. I get the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(sigwhat) : 
system is singular for the calculator: reciprocal condition number = 2.20034e-29
```

**How can I solve that issue?**

Also I wanted to use anova test or the lrtest but both I could not get to work (**if someone has an idea to that I would really appreciate that**)

r-Code:

```
lm04 <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(sic = factor(sic), fdyear = factor(fdyear)) %>%
  group_by(sic, fdyear) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split()  %>% 
  map(.f = function(df){
    gvlma(lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt + dt, data=Relevante_V03)) %>% 
  gvlma()
})
```

My Data looks something like this:

| Name | Segment | marketingspending | Year | R_at_py | sale_py_at_py | txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3401 | 10000 | 2000 | 200000 | 1.134 | 19180 |
| A | 3401 | 20000 | 2001 | 250000 | 1.333 | 32980 |
| B | 2201 | 15000 | 2004 | 280000 | 1.465 | 52280 |
| B | 2201 | 23000 | 2009 | 320000 | 1.789 | 591212 |
| B | 2201 | 28000 | 2010 | 390000 | 2.166 | 322220 |
| C | 2201 | 30000 | 2000 | 210000 | 1.244 | 192023 |
| C | 2201 | 18000 | 2004 | 200000 | 1.044 | 170046 |
| D | 1 | 28000 | 2000 | 400000 | 2.039 | 678392 |
| D | 1 | 38000 | 2001 | 521000 | 2.455 | 733218 |

Segment=sic, fdyear=year,Intr= interest rate, sale_py_at_py= sale(previous year)/ asset(previous year), R_at_py= 1/asset(previous year), dt= dept, txt = tax

Also I need to do the glm function. I used almost the same function:

```
lm04.1 <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(sic = factor(sic), fdyear = factor(fdyear)) %>%
  group_by(sic, fdyear) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split()  %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    glm( formula = marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt + dt, data=Relevante_V03) %>% 
  glm()
})
```

As a result I get a list of 98 with each a length of 30.

But I want to get information similar to the following (what should normally come out if you don't group):

```
Call:
glm( formula = marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt + dt, data=Relevante_V03)

Deviance Residuals:
Min         1Q      Median        2Q           Max

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std.       Error      t value    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)
Intr
Sale_py_at_py
R_at_py
txt
dt
———
Signif. Codes:     0 ´***´     0.001 ´**´     0.01´**´   0.01 ´*´

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be )

Null deviance:
Residual deviance:
AIC:

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations:
```

So how can I achieve that and how can I control that every group gives the same output for glm?

Comment: I do not understand. For me it is not reproducible. Would you be so kind to clarify what you really want and add a small reproducible example. Thank you very much. Here in your Data there is no column sic, marketingspending...

Comment: Okay tried my best. Let me know if there is still something unclear :) (could not add also the last missing variables of the lm() function)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such a solution:
I changed some columns (due to lack of the others):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df %>% 
  mutate(Name = as_factor(Name)) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_df(.f = function(df){
    glm(marketingspending ~ sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt, data =df) %>% 
      glance %>% 
      add_column(Name = unique(df$Name), .before=1)
  })
```

```
  Name  null.deviance df.null logLik    AIC    BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <fct>         <dbl>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 A          50000000       1   45.9  -85.9  -89.8 1.32e-21           0     2
2 B          86000000       2   71.0 -134.  -138.  4.76e-22           0     3
3 C          72000000       1   49.1  -92.3  -96.2 5.29e-23           0     2
4 D          50000000       1   49.1  -92.3  -96.2 5.29e-23           0     2
```

Comment: Holy I just noticed that I am using glm instead of gvlma sorry. If I try to use gvlma I get the error: Error in solve.default(sigwhat) : 
system is singular for the calculator: reciprocal condition number = 2.20034e-29

Comment: Only thing I can provide is that: `model1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)
gvlma(model1)` gives what `gvlma` is for: `                    Value p-value                Decision
Global Stat        2.1036  0.7167 Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           0.7695  0.3804 Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           0.1043  0.7467 Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      0.7339  0.3916 Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 0.4959  0.4813 Assumptions acceptable.`

Comment: Hmm do you have a solution to the glm approach?